# Pass Data between two different controllers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an application in Laravel. I need to pass some data between two methods in two different controllers. Let me explain You,

I have a controller sellerRegisterController which has a method verifySeller,

```
class sellerRegisterController extends Controller
{

public function verifySeller()
{
//some logic here

}

}
```

The above veirfySeller method works on some logic and create a varible ID, I want to pass that varible ID data to another method (submitSellerDetails) in different controller (sellerDetailsController).

```
class sellerDetailsContorller extends Controller
    {

    public function submitSellerDetails()
    {
    //some logic here
    }

    }
```

In a nutshell I want to know how can I pass data/variable from one method to another in different controllers? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for separating these out into two controllers instead of just having everything in a SellerController?

Comment: @GageLaFleur ok lets assume I put both methods in same controller how Can I pass the data then between two methods in same controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would define both methods `verifySeller()` and `submitSellerDetails()` in the same controller.

Your controller will look like this:

```
class sellerRegisterController extends Controller
{

    public function verifySeller( Request $request )
    {
         //some logic here

         // passing data to another method in the same controller
         $this->submitSellerDetails( $request );
    }

    public function submitSellerDetails( Request $request )
    {
      //some logic here
    }

}
```

If you don't want to pass `$request` variable but some other variable instead, you can do something like this:

```
class sellerRegisterController extends Controller
{

    public function verifySeller( Request $request )
    {
         //some logic here

         // passing data to another method in the same controller
         $this->submitSellerDetails( $variableContainingYourData );
    }

    public function submitSellerDetails( $someArgument )
    {
      //some logic here
    }
}
```

There's another way to handle it. You can define a variable in the in your controller, assign it whatever data you want inside `verifySeller()` method and then call `submitSellerDetails()` method and use that variable inside it.

**Update:**

```
class sellerRegisterController extends Controller
{
    private $someVariable;

    public function verifySeller( Request $request )
    {
         //some logic here

         // assign data which you want to access inside submitSellerDetails()
         $this->someVariable = 'some data';

         // calling submitSellerDetails() method
         $this->submitSellerDetails();
    }

    public function submitSellerDetails()
    {
      //some logic here

      //do whatever you want with $this->someVariable;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ok so how will I be able to get the variable data in second method? Like for passing I can use this line $this->submitSellerDetails( $variableContainingYourData );. How can I get the value in submitSellerDetals?

Comment: `$someArgument` should contain the data passed from `verifySeller` method. Seems like your basics are pretty weak and you need to do some work on it. Let me modify my answer and add some more detail.